# Different sized icons on desktop?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, icons

Windows (7 is what I'm running, but whatever):

Is it possible to have different sized icons?  For instance, have all but 1 be the standard size but then have 1 be extra large?

I'd like to enlarge commonly used icons on my desktop but not all icons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe there is a gadget that can act as an application launcher for 1 application using a custom icon. You'd have 1 gadget for each application for which you'd want to have a bigger icon.

If such a gadget does not exist, you could create it yourself, for your preferred applications. See [**this tutorial**](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/window-on-windows/?p=575) where they explain how to launch My Computer from a gadget. It could be adapted for any application by changing some lines.

**Edit**: I tried the instructions in the tutorial and came up with this "Google Earth" gadget. It is bigger than the regular desktop icons and it works fine, launching Google Earth when clicking on it. I found the icon on the Net (thanks Google Image).

[image]

Here is what the Add Gadget window looks like with the new Google Earth gadget (see author and website ;-) ).

[image]

Comment: Good idea. Perhaps even better would be a gadget that has a built in configuration option, so that you wouldn't need to create a new gadget for each icon.

Comment: I agree, but I could not find one yet that fits the bill.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say without using 3rd party software, **this cannot be done**

And even then, I'd think you'd be hard pressed to find anything that can, since Aero (the UI-theme) also effects icons. That means they would have to tweak Aero to tweak your icons and from what I've read so far, that's not easy...

Comment: I hope for your sake, someone proves me wrong

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the answer is no unless there is a Windows 7 theme that uses [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics).  I know the [KDE4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE_4) plasma desktop can do this, but that's the only one I know about.

Answer (score 0):

you can have diferent size icons with the help of rainmeter, custom size and all the settings are there also app linking and sorts.