# Is there a way to have different size icons on the desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, desktop, icons

I basically want 1 extra large icon (e.g. my Daily To Do list) and the rest could be regular.

I know that in the past [with Windows Vista & 7 you could use a "Gadget"](https://superuser.com/questions/64615/different-sized-icons-on-desktop?rq=1), but that is no longer the case.

I'd be happy with either something that's built into Windows or a 3rd party software (free or paid).

I am on Windows 8.1

Comment: Haven't used it personally but there's http://8gadgetpack.net/ to add gadgets (back) to Windows 8/10

Comment: yes, you can reinstall the Gadgets in WIn8.1/10 easily: http://superuser.com/a/948068/174557